# How to track owner and timestamp of query executed from biguquery UI

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a system to track all the queries executed on Google Bigquery. We are essentially using google cloud APIs through gcloud utility, to track DDL/DML query, we are storing username and query execution duration and timestamp on DB.

However, in those APIs, I am not able to track the DDL query where the table created or deleted directly from Bigquery UI. Is there any way to track who and when fired those query

Answer (score 0):

In the BigQuery UI you can check the [Query History](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui#viewing_query_history) to view the query details such as:

- Job ID
- User
- Location Creation time
- Start time
- End time
- Duration
- Bytes processed
- Bytes billed
- Job priority
- Destination table
- Use legacy SQL

Click the Query History link in the navigation panel. In the query history details panel, click an individual query job to see the details or to open the query in the query editor. When you open the query in the query editor, you can repeat the query by clicking Run query.

[image]

I made a couple of tests by using DDL statements such as:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE Example
( 
   x INT64,
   y STRING
);

INSERT INTO Example
VALUES (5, 'foo');

INSERT INTO Example
VALUES (6, 'bar');

SELECT *
FROM Example;
```

And I was able to get the query information by using the BigQuery UI

Comment: what if we create a table using UI instead of executing a query?

Comment: I have noticed the behavior mentioned, It seems that BigQuery doesn't show the job in the Query history neither with the command "bq ls", for that reason I suggest you raise a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) asking for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can not see the table created/deleted when using the UI with the Query history. But, you can see the logs in [Stackdriver logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview#getting_started) filtering by BigQuery. There is no BQ job created but there is a call to the API that can be tracked through the logs.

Answer (score 0):

From the [BigQuery Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs#message_formats), you can search for InsertTable (`google.cloud.bigquery.v2.TableService.InsertTable`) and DeleteTable (`google.cloud.bigquery.v2.TableService.DeleteTable`) operations. If there are actions of this types, they are shown the `methodName` field, see example below. I got it with this query:

```
resource.type="bigquery_dataset"
"InsertTable" OR "DeleteTable"
```

From each log entry returned by the search above check for the `principalEmail` and `timestamp`, even, you can look at `requestMetadata` to get more infor about the culprit. Here an example:

```
{
 insertId: "yyyzzz"  
 logName: "projects/my-project/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"  
 protoPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"   
  authenticationInfo: {
   principalEmail: "user@test.com"    
  }
  authorizationInfo: [1]   
  metadata: {…}   
  methodName: "google.cloud.bigquery.v2.TableService.DeleteTable"   
  requestMetadata: {
   callerIp: "189.00.00.00"    
   callerSuppliedUserAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 12739.105.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.158 Safari/537.36,gzip(gfe)"    
   destinationAttributes: {…}    
   requestAttributes: {…}    
  }
  resourceName: "projects/my-project/datasets/my-dataset/tables/my-table"   
  serviceName: "bigquery.googleapis.com"   
  status: {
  }
 }
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-03-31T16:51:31.977240157Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 severity: "NOTICE"  
 timestamp: "2020-03-31T16:51:31.590Z"  
}
```